# Three Table Join MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three mysql tables with a connecting unique id in each

### Episodes

---

#### epis_epsiode_id || epis_title

```
123                Test
456                Another Test
```

---

### Watch List

---

#### wali_pisode_id || wali_status || wali_user_id

```
123               1              16
```

---

### Watch Log

---

#### wast_episode_id || wast_status || wast_user_id

```
456                1              16
```

---

The above shows two episodes with episode `123` added to user `16` watch list and episode `456` logged a watched by the same user.

What I need to do is build a query which returns all of the the `Episodes` and where the user_id in both `Watch List` and `Watch Log` is = `16` display the status for each table against the episode row or else show `null`

I can get one table join working but when I add in another well, hence the reason for the question.

I am aware of other questions similar to this but having tried the majority of the answers given I am still struggling to get the desired result.

Could some one very kind an helpful post a query example that would achieve the above?

Thanks

***EDIT***

```
SELECT 
    e.*, 
    wl.wali_status,
    ws.wast_status 
FROM 
    meta_episodes e
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    app_watch_list wl
    ON wl.wali_episode_id = e.epis_episode_id
    AND wl.wali_user_id = 16
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    app_watch_status ws
    ON ws.wast_episode_id = e.epis_episode_id
    AND ws.wast_user_id = 16
```

***Desired Results***

### Results

---

#### epis_episode_id || epis_title || wali_status || wast_status

---

```
123                Test          1              NULL
456                Another…      NULL           1
```

---

Comment: I didn't include one as none seemed to work as I intended, I could post an example of what I was doing, however I didn't think it would help the contributors

Comment: Wouldn't also harm, right?

Comment: SQL JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Comment: You could achieve this kind of thing with a UNION, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp is a good place to start understanding about them.

Comment: It would show slightly more research effort if you included your query (even if it doesn't work as intended). Including the query may also help people answer accurately and in more detail.

Comment: You should post what is your desired result set

Comment: Added my query as request thanks @Alexander for the nudge ;)

Comment: @micb `UNION` is hardly what's needed here

Comment: @Lamak Added disired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT  E.epis_episode_id, 
        E.epis_title,
        WLI.wali_status,
        WLO.wast_status
FROM `Episodes` AS E
LEFT JOIN `Watch List` AS WLI
    ON E.epis_episode_id = WLI.wali_episode_id
    AND WLI.wali_user_id = 16
LEFT JOIN `Watch Log` AS WLO
    ON E.epis_episode_id = WLO.wast_episode_id
    AND WLO.wast_user_id = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.*, wali_status, wast_status
FROM meta_episodes e
LEFT JOIN app_watch_list wl ON e.epis_epsiode_id = wl.wali_episode_id AND wali_user_id = 16
LEFT JOIN app_watch_status ws ON e.epis_epsiode_id = ws.wast_episode_id AND wast_user_id = 16
```

More on fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/071751/13

Comment: Thanks for this however this only returns results where there are values in the two link tables of `app_watch_list` & `app_watch_status` I am looking to return all episodes

Comment: Then just remove the `WHERE wali_user_id = 16 OR wast_user_id = 16`